# Spring Retryable annotation not working in mvc application

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I am new to spring framework.I have started using Retryable annotation in my mvc application.I have added @EnableRetry on my config class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableRetry
class ApplicationConfig {
```

I have my MachinesContainer class in which I am calling some other REST APIs.On that method I have used @Retryable annotation with configuration provided to that.

```
@Retryable(value = {NullPointerException.class},maxAttempts = 3,backoff = @Backoff(2000))
public static void getMachineContainer(ResponseEntity<MachinesContainer> machinesContainer,String ipsByGeoUrl,HttpEntity<?> requestEntity) throws Exception {

    if(machinesContainer==null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    machinesContainer = restTemplate
            .exchange(ipsByGeoUrl, HttpMethod.POST,
                    requestEntity, MachinesContainer.class);

}
```

It directly calls to exception instead of calling "getMachineContainer" 3 times.

```
@Component
public class Query{
@Override
public MachinesContainer getIpsByGeo(String city, String state, String country) {


    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    String query = bundle.getString("ipsByGeo.sqlQuery");

    // Build Map with params to IPsByGeo query
    HashMap<String, String> args = new HashMap<String, String>();
    args.put("cityKey", city.trim().toUpperCase());
    args.put("countryKey", country.trim());
    if (state != null && state.length() >= 1) {
        args.put("stateClause", " and r.state='" + state.trim() + "'");
    } else {
        args.put("stateClause", "");
    }

    //Generate query with values
    StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(args,"$","$");
    query = sub.replace(query);

    HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(query, headers);

    String environment = System.getenv(SERVICE_ENVIRONMENT);
    logger.debug("getIpsByGeo service environment is:{}",environment);
    String ipsByGeoUrl = <Some API URL>;

    try {
        ResponseEntity<MachinesContainer> machinesContainer = null;

        getMachineContainer(machinesContainer,ipsByGeoUrl,requestEntity);

        return machinesContainer.getBody();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
}
```

Please suggest some solutions.

I am using spring version - 4.2.3.RELEASE
Java version - 1.8
spring-retry - 1.2.1.RELEASE
spring-aop - 4.2.5.RELEASE
aspectjweaver - 1.8.8

Comment: how are you calling this function . show that code

Comment: you are calling a static method it won't work.

Comment: @pvpkiran I have edited the code...now check

Comment: @JEY even I have removed the static keyword.still not working

Comment: @pvpkiran I have also checked by writing the "getMachineContainer" function code in "getIpsByGeo" function...it was not working.

Comment: This function is called from function having @scheduling annotation.Can this be an issue ?

Comment: that doesn't matter. How are you calling getIpsByGeo

Comment: @pvpkiran getIpsByGeo is called by some other class function which is having Scheduling annotation...I cannot give my whole code here.

Comment: Do you create an object of Query class or do you autowire it in the calling class

Comment: @pvpkiran I have autowired Query class in that caller class.

Comment: Even if you get this to work, there is no point in retrying this, since the `machinesContainer` won't change between retries. If it's `null` the first time, it will be null each time.

Comment: @GaryRussell I was just trying the Retryable annotation,thats why I have added that "if" condition at starting of function.

Comment: Re `@Scheduled` - I don't know if this is the cause, but there was recently a [bug fix where `@Retryable` and `@Scheduled`  on the same bean didn't work](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16196)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things
1. `@Retryable` ia based on Spring AOP which uses proxy, and hence it doesn't work with private method calls(I mean methods in the same class)
2. Same applies to static methods.

Comment: I have also checked by writing the "getMachineContainer" function code in "getIpsByGeo" function...it was not working.

Comment: can you show that piece of code. If you put getMachineContainer function code in getIpsByGeo, where did you put `@Retryable`. And also how are you calling `getIpsByGeo`  function?

Comment: I have placed the same code from "getMachineContainer" function into "getIpsByGeo" function.